# Do aggregations and statistics on a very large Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large (larger than cheaper RAM) CSV data set that I'm operating with pandas. Now I'm doing something like

```
df = pd.read_csv('verylargefile.csv', chunksize=10000)
for df_chunk in df:
    df_chunk['new_column'] = df_chunk['old_column'].apply(my_func)
    # do other operations and filters...
    df_chunk.to_csv('processed.csv', mode='a')
```

so I can do what I need to operate on the data set and save the output to another file.

The problem starts with doing some groupings and statistics on this data set: I need to calculate the mean, standard deviation and histograms of the entire data set and also graph the results, tendencies, use statsmodels etc. As the samples are not going to be homogeneous I cannot calculate the statistics.

```
df.groupby('column_1').sum()
TypeError: Cannot groupby on a TextFileReader
```

I don't have the usual options of selecting only a few columns and I don't see how storing my data on HDF would help. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a situation where [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) could help.   I have included an example below.

For more information see the [dask documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html) and this very nice [tutorial](https://github.com/blaze/dask-tutorial).

```
In [1]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [2]: !head data/accounts.0.csv
id,names,amount
138,Ray,1502
1,Tim,5
388,Ingrid,45
202,Zelda,1324
336,Jerry,-1607
456,Laura,-2832
65,Laura,-326
54,Yvonne,341
92,Sarah,3136

In [3]: dask_df = dd.read_csv('data/accounts.0.csv', chunkbytes=4000000)

In [4]: dask_df.npartitions
Out[4]: 4

In [5]: len(dask_df)
Out[5]: 1000000

In [6]: result = dask_df.groupby('names').sum()

In [7]: result.compute()
Out[7]: 
                id    amount
names                       
Alice     10282524  43233084
Bob        8617531  47512276
Charlie    8056803  47729638
Dan       10146581  32513817
Edith     15164281  37806024
Frank     11310157  63869156
George    14941235  80436603
Hannah     3006336  25721574
Ingrid    10123877  54152865
Jerry     10317245   8613040
Kevin      6809100  16755317
Laura      9941112  34723055
Michael   11200937  36431387
Norbert    5715799  14482698
Oliver    10423117  32415534
Patricia  15289085  22767501
Quinn     10686459  16083432
Ray       10156429   9455663
Sarah      7977036  34970428
Tim       12283567  47851141
Ursula     4893696  37942347
Victor     8864468  15542688
Wendy      9348077  68824579
Xavier     6600945  -3482124
Yvonne     5665415  12701550
Zelda      8491817  42573021
```

For comparison here is the result using `pandas`.  The data that I am using here fits in memory, but `dask` will work even when the data is larger than memory.

```
In [8]: import pandas as pd

In [9]: pandas_df = pd.read_csv('data/accounts.0.csv')

In [10]: len(pandas_df)
Out[10]: 1000000

In [11]: pandas_df.groupby('names').sum()
Out[11]: 
                id    amount
names                       
Alice     10282524  43233084
Bob        8617531  47512276
Charlie    8056803  47729638
Dan       10146581  32513817
Edith     15164281  37806024
Frank     11310157  63869156
George    14941235  80436603
Hannah     3006336  25721574
Ingrid    10123877  54152865
Jerry     10317245   8613040
Kevin      6809100  16755317
Laura      9941112  34723055
Michael   11200937  36431387
Norbert    5715799  14482698
Oliver    10423117  32415534
Patricia  15289085  22767501
Quinn     10686459  16083432
Ray       10156429   9455663
Sarah      7977036  34970428
Tim       12283567  47851141
Ursula     4893696  37942347
Victor     8864468  15542688
Wendy      9348077  68824579
Xavier     6600945  -3482124
Yvonne     5665415  12701550
Zelda      8491817  42573021
```

Answer (score 1):

Type of `df` isn't `dataframe`, but `TextFileReader`. I think you need concat all chunks to dataframe by function [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and then apply function:

```
df = pd.read_csv('verylargefile.csv', chunksize=10000) # gives TextFileReader

df_chunk = concat(df, ignore_index=True)
df_chunk['new_column'] = df_chunk['old_column'].apply(my_func)
# do other operations and filters...
df_chunk.to_csv('processed.csv', mode='a')
```

[More info](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking).

EDIT:

Maybe helps this approach: process large dataframe by its groups:

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

#test data
temp=u"""id,col1,col2,col3
1,13,15,14
1,13,15,14
1,12,15,13
2,18,15,13
2,18,15,13
2,18,15,13
2,18,15,13
2,18,15,13
2,18,15,13
3,14,16,13
3,14,15,13
3,14,185,213"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=",", usecols=['id', 'col1'])
#drop duplicities, from out you can choose constant
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print df
#   id  col1
#0   1    13
#2   1    12
#3   2    18
#9   3    14

#for example list of constants
constants = [1,2,3]
#or column id to list of unique values
constants = df['id'].unique().tolist()
print constants
#[1L, 2L, 3L]

for i in constants:
    iter_csv = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), delimiter=",", chunksize=10)
    #concat subset with rows id == constant
    df = pd.concat([chunk[chunk['id'] == i] for chunk in iter_csv])
    #your groupby function
    data = df.reset_index(drop=True).groupby(["id","col1"], as_index=False).sum()
    print data.to_csv(index=False)

    #id,col1,col2,col3
    #1,12,15,13
    #1,13,30,28
    #
    #id,col1,col2,col3
    #2,18,90,78
    #
    #id,col1,col2,col3
    #3,14,215,239
```

Comment: Not really. The problem is exactly this: if I do a concat I would not have enough memory to do anything. That's why I have to use chunks.

Comment: Thanks again, but I don't have a lot of constants on my dataframe and even one column would surpass what I have of RAM (as I said in the question) so any concat wouldn't help.